# Get distance height with accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer, core-motion

I have searched for hours now and still didn't find a definitive answer to my problem. 
The scenario is this: the user throw an iPhone as high as he can and I want to measure the height that the iPhone has done.
I want to use the accelerometer with Core Motion and I successfully implemented a simple system that gives me the acceleration on the 3 axis. This is an acceleration though.
Based on my physics knowledge, the formula to calculate the maximum height is (V0^2)/2*g  where V0 is the starting velocity. 
I have the acceleration velocity though.

Any idea how can I convert the acceleration to velocity or directly get the velocity from my accelerometer?

I know it's not a completely programming related question, but I just want to have some help on this :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is alredy an app that does exactly what you are up to: [Send Me To Heaven](http://carrotpop.com/Carrot_Pop/smth.html). You won't find it in Apple's App Store because it never passed the review, guess why ;-)

As you stated you only have access to accelerations. h = v<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>/(2*g) is correct. To get the starting velocity v<sub>0</sub> you need to [integrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) the acceleration numerically over the time. The trickiest part will be to find necessary and sufficient conditions to determine the time interval [t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub>]. When did the acceleration phase start and when did it stop.

Another thing to consider is to avoid cheating users who just perform a rotation around there axis for a couple of seconds, then simulate the flying phase. There you might consider the landing phase too: when the user grabs the device you should register a strong deceleration.

However, don't expect this app to ever get in the store and at Google Play the competitors were faster.

Comment: I saw that, my idea is broken now :(

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

There's a number of problems physics impose on you (other than the velocity), to get the result.

1. The angle of the throw, relative to the direction of gravity. You cant know the relative vertical distance, unless you know this angle.
2. Orientation of reference throughout the throw (you cannot deduct the speed from the acceleration, from the device itself, unless you account for the changes in rotation while the phone accelerates).

However! You can decide to assume certain things, which will make these annoying problems go away!

**Reasonable assumption:**

1. The device is caught again, at the same relative height it was thrown.

This assumption reduce the problem to a much simpler one, in which we only really need to find the duration of time, where the device is in free fall, in order to determine the relative height of the throw.

**All you have to do:**

To determine if the device is in free fall, is relatively easy, since the total gravity would be near 0 m/s^2.

However, there's still one smallish problem to this, because the accelerometer is probably not located at the center of mass of the phone, so it will experience a constant acceleration (if the phone rotates around itself) in exactly one particular direction, throughout the free fall.

The maths of determining the height of a vertical throw, based on the airtime duration is left as an exercise to the reader :-)